# Open my application on reboot for all users

Tags: startup

I am a new Rust learner and I recently came across an idea for a simple reminder application, sort of like an alarm.
My question is how do I make sure my binary is always executed on reboot of system? I am looking for both Windows 10 and Ubuntu answers and I know very few things about Daemons on Linux, so I am not exactly an expert. Please provide learning resources to do this too if possible.

Comment: This is not really a Rust question. You may need to ask a different question per operating system that you are interested in.

Comment: As an Ubuntu user myself, I would prefer to have a binary that just does what it does and take responsibility myself for when and how it runs.

Comment: @PeterHall I don't necessarily disagree but it's common for software to either ship with the relevant predefined files, or install themselves (the latter especially on windows, usually as an option in the installer).

Comment: Anyway Vaibhav you want to look at *services*, this is the terminology for windows, as well as for ubuntu (for ubuntu a systemd service is defined via a *unit file*). For non-systemd distributions you want to look for *rc files* and daemons, and for macOS it's *launchd agents* (but the documentation of launchd is... bad)

Comment: @Masklinn ok, I will look into that. Thank you for sharing this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ubuntu if you want an application or a script to be executed after a reboot, you can use crontab.

Just open your ubuntu terminal and type

```
crontab -e
```

That will open a file, and in that file you can type the following as an example:

```
@reboot bash /home/start.sh
```